# MultiBinding to Value does not work in WPF .Net CORE 3

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, multibinding

I have the following items in a class, where strings bind properly to a TextBlock:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Total lessons that where in the batch
    /// </summary>
    public int LessonsInBatch           = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Total lessons that are left in the batch
    /// </summary>
    public int LessonsInBatchLeft       => _lessonsBatch?.Count ?? 0;
```

I tried all of the following but nont works, and the StringFormat is always empty (eg. "bla foo {0}' is always ''):

```
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment  = "Right"       VerticalAlignment    = "Center"
                   Grid.Column          = "1"           Grid.Row             = "0"
                   Margin               = "10, 0, 0, 0" FontWeight           = "Bold"
                   FontSize             = "12"          FontFamily           = "Arial Black">

            <Run Text="{Binding LessonsInBatchLeft}, StringFormat=' {0}'}"/>
            <Run Text=" of "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding LessonsInBatch}, StringFormat=' {0:N}'}"/>

        </TextBlock>
```

or

```
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment  = "Right"       VerticalAlignment    = "Center"
                   Grid.Column          = "1"           Grid.Row             = "0"
                   Margin               = "10, 0, 0, 0" FontWeight           = "Bold"
                   FontSize             = "12"          FontFamily           = "Arial Black">

            <Run Text="{Binding LessonsInBatchLeft}"/>
            <Run Text=" of "/>
            <Run Text="{Binding LessonsInBatch}"/>

        </TextBlock>
```

or

```
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment  = "Right"       VerticalAlignment    = "Center"
                   Grid.Column          = "1"           Grid.Row             = "0"
                   Margin               = "10, 0, 0, 0" FontWeight           = "Bold"
                   FontSize             = "12"          FontFamily           = "Arial Black">

            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}}{0} of {1}">
                    <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="LessonsInBatchLeft" />
                    <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="LessonsInBatch" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>

        </TextBlock>
```

I really don't know what to try else.

Binding for strings work, just not for Integers...

Comment: `public int LessonsInBatch = 0;` is a field, not a property. You can only bind to properties.

Comment: What should I say?! Sometimes it is right in front of you! :o) Thanks for pointing that out!!!